# Sending Firebase Notification with nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an android app on which I want to send notification via my web app.

How do I send Firebase Cloud Messaging notification with nodejs? I have found a lot of examples and posts on this subject, but in all of them you are supposed to just paste device Token and send notification to that device. If I wanted to use it that way, I would be able to simply implement this from official documentation.

The thing is, I need to receive user id from database so I know which user I want to send notification. After I have user id I can then retrieve device Token from the same database. I get both user id and device token on client side. And documentation refers to server side.

This all happen after button click. So, I don't understand how to send notification on server side, meaning, I don't have there all those informations I need - user id, device token and message info that contain some other database info. Do I pass those arguments from client side to server side somehow, or is there a way of using modules like "require()" on client side?
What is the best approach here?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to implement a device token registry to fit with your use case. So if you want to send messages to users, then you will need a registry (really just a fancy word for a database) of the token(s) for each user. Then when you want to send a specific user a message, you look up their token(s) in the registry, and call the FCM API to send messages to them. Since you mention Node.js, you can likely do this using the Firebase Admin SDK: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#send_to_individual_devices.

An alternative I have once written [article about using a topic for each user](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html), which saves having to have a registry of their tokens. While this is less secure (since anyone who knows a topic, can subscribe to it), it is definitely easier to implement.

Comment: You didn't understand my question. I have a record in database which contain token info and it's updated with onTokenRefresh() on mobile app. So that's not a problem. 
The problem with Admin SDK is that it's server side and I retrieve user ID and Token on client side, in HTML page when specific user is clicked. 

I don't understand how to implement that with Admin SDK. I have user ID and Token, and notification must be send after button click. All that is in html page. 
How do I get that same user ID and token, which I retrieved in html page, on server side .js file?